# How to prepend value to the cat command output without modifying a file?

Tags: bash, pipe

At work, there is a custom script that I must use to apply a SQL script to a mysql database server and have no liberty to modify. The command line options of the custom script is very limited. For example, it does not allow specification of the default database. i.e. I have to `use database` to switch to the right catalog.

Now I want to apply `create table` scripts to the database. However, I need to have `use database` statement in the first line for the `create table` script to run successfully.

If the following works, I wouldn't need to post a question here:

```
echo 'use database' | cat create_tables.sql | work_send_command_to_db.sh
```

I really want to be able to achieve the goal without modifying the file locally. It is because in the example command above, `create_tables.sql` is already checked into git. I don't want to need to reset the repository after each application of the `create_tables.sql` script.

Comment: `cat` is ignoring `stdin` because you gave it a filename argument: your pipe approach would likely work if you wrote `cat - create_tables.sql` to tell it to concatenate both (although [muru's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/556551/65304) is cleaner)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pipe the output of both commands as a group to the final script, not the output of `echo` to `cat`. So group those commands using `{ ...; }` or `(...)`:

```
{ echo 'use database'; cat create_tables.sql; } | work_send_command_to_db.sh
```

Or:

```
( echo 'use database'; cat create_tables.sql ) | work_send_command_to_db.sh
```